# Memory requirement of Ubercart?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am setting up a shopping cart for a client and will host the new site on a separate VPS. What is the typical memory required to run a Ubercart site? We are targeting a few thousand users, around a hundred products, and under ten concurrent users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal 7 requires a minimum of 32MB (see - http://drupal.org/requirements/php) however in reality it will require much more, simple sites with a few contributed modules should be around 96MB.

Personally I'd recommend 128MB minimum and then tweak as required.

You can use the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module to output the pages memory usage to help you.